# Angular sce.trustAsUrl and javascript hrefs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a page that has a bookmarklet on like so:

```
<a ng-href="{{getBookmarklet()}}">Bookmarklet</a>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.getBookmarklet = function() {
     return 'javascript:alert(1)';
  }
}
```

The href gets sanitised as unsafe:javascript:alert(1). So, I've tried using sce.trustAs to prevent this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.getBookmarklet = function() {
     return $sce.trustAsUrl('javascript:alert(1)');
  }
}
```

However, I still get the 'unsafe' prefix on my URLs. I've also tried trustAsJs, with no luck. I don't want to whitelist javascript: URLs throughout my app with compileProvider, just allow this one instance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and was able to work around it by using `$sce.trustAsHtml()` instead.

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.getBookmarklet = function() {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="javascript:alert(1)">Bookmarklet</a>');
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="::getBookmarklet()"></ng-bind-html>
```

This probably poses issues with CSS and other directives, but such issues can usually be worked around.